# Error in triggering mails through simple program

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to trigger a mail through program But i am getting error as below.
     can it be possible that i can trigger mail to dam.da@abc.com using host  192.168.195.68 and default port 25 with default instance so that i dont have create another session and pass passswords and different username. Please help me on this.

[image]

```
![import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String \[\] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "dam.da@abc.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "dam.da@abc.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "192.168.195.68";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Since the exception says there is a timeout, did you check manually whether the connection can be established at all?

Comment: Try telnet on that IP and Port